# Using a Map in XSL for expanding abbreviations

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

I saw a similar question on creating a Map.

That answer has this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="map">
        <map>
            <entry key="key-1">value1</entry>
            <entry key="key-2">value2</entry>
            <entry key="key-3">value3</entry>
        </map>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($map)/map/entry[@key='key-1']"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

I would like to replace the output command to use a value in my XML to see if it is a key in the map and then replace it with the value.

Is the best way to do a for-each select on the map and compare with contains?

Here is a snippet of the XML:

```
<document>
   <content name="PART_DESC_SHORT" type="text" vse-streams="2" u="22" action="cluster" weight="1">
   SCREW - ADJUST
   </content>
</document>
```

The content node value may have a string containing an abbreviation that I want to replace with the full value.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: I need to search all the keys and find if the key is contained within that nodes value. So if the node has: 'Brkt Pivot R' change it to 'Bracket Pivot R'

Comment: If you gove a better example (XML document and corresponding wanted result), I might be able to help.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Some of the abbreviations are only 2 letters like 'Br'. I'm actually using EXSLT not Microsoft. I noticed they have a toikenize function. The string of PART_DESC_SHORT should be tokenized by space and apply abbreviation expansion for exact match, not contains. I tried both solutions below.

Comment: Paul Blackburn: I don't see any abbreviations in the string value of the `content` element. Also, it contains a hyphen, whivh would be tokenized as a separate word if the separator is space. Please, edit the question and correct these and other issues.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a `for-each` - this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

  <xsl:variable name="abbreviations">
    <abbreviation key="Brkt Pivot R">Bracket Pivot R</abbreviation>
    <abbreviation key="Foo">Expanded Foo</abbreviation>
    <abbreviation key="Bar">Expanded Bar</abbreviation>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:variable name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="abbreviation" select="msxsl:node-set($abbreviations)/*[@key=$text]"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$abbreviation">
        <xsl:value-of select="$abbreviation"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will convert any XML in an exact copy expanding all the text matching an abbreviation defined in the `abbreviations` variable at the top.

If you want to expand the abbreviations only within specific elements you can modify the second template `match="..."` rule.

On the other hand if you want to expand ANY occurance of all the abbreviations within the text you need loops - that means recursion in XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

  <xsl:variable name="abbreviations">
    <abbreviation key="Brkt">Bracket</abbreviation>
    <abbreviation key="As">Assembly</abbreviation>
    <abbreviation key="Foo">Expanded Foo</abbreviation>
    <abbreviation key="Bar">Expanded Bar</abbreviation>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- Replaces all occurrences of a string with another within a text -->
  <xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="from"/>
    <xsl:param name="to"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$from)">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($text,$from),$to)"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$from)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="from" select="$from"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="to" select="$to"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace all occurences of a list of abbreviation with their expanded version -->
  <xsl:template name="replaceAbbreviations">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="abbreviations"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count($abbreviations)>0">
        <xsl:call-template name="replaceAbbreviations">
          <xsl:with-param name="text">
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
              <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="from" select="$abbreviations[1]/@key"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="to" select="$abbreviations[1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="abbreviations" select="$abbreviations[position()>1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="replaceAbbreviations">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="abbreviations" select="msxsl:node-set($abbreviations)/*"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applying this second XSLT to

```
<document>
  <content name="PART_DESC_SHORT" type="text" vse-streams="2" u="22" action="cluster" weight="1">
    Brkt Pivot R
  </content>
</document>
```

produces

```
<document>
  <content name="PART_DESC_SHORT" type="text" vse-streams="2" u="22" action="cluster" weight="1">
    Bracket Pivot R
  </content>
</document>
```

Note that:

- this solution assumes that no abbreviation ovelap (e.g. two separate abbreviations `Brk` and `Brkt`)
- it uses XSLT 1.0 - a better solution is probably possible with XSLT 2.0
- this kind of heavy string processing is likely quite inefficient in XSLT, it is probably better to write an extension function in some other language and call it from the XSLT.

Comment: The only thing is that PART_DESC_SHORT could have text of 'Brkt Pivot R' or just 'Brkt' or 'Brkt As' etc in fact the last value would be expanded to 'Bracket Assembly' as 2 terms get expanded. my abbreviation key would just have 'Brkt' to 'Bracket'

Comment: I modified your choose statement to : <content name="PART_DESC_SHORT" type="text">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$abbreviation">
        <xsl:value-of select="$abbreviation" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </content>

Comment: That modification works for my xml when 'Brkt' was the value, but if the value is 'Brkt Pivot R' it does not. I only put 'Brkt' as abbreviation, not 'Brkt Pivot R'.

Comment: If I process an XML that contains 'Brkt Pivot R' as the text of any element with my second XSLT I obtain the same XML with the text 'Bracket Pivot R' - that I think is what you want. I don't understand the change in the `choose` statement - the XSLT works as is in my answer.

Comment: Very interesting. While I don't appear to have abbreviation overlap, I did notice that this doesn't quite work if the word is already expanded like 'Valve Rocker' gets expanded to 'Valvee Rocker', where I have 'Valv' as expanded to 'Valve'. Also, this should work on each separated word within the string. I noticed several expansions within a word. For instance I have 'BR' to 'Bearing' so 'Bracket' could be expanded to 'Bearingacket'.

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanations. I'm rather new to XSL/XSLT/XPATH. Yeah, If I could tokenize the string like in Java it would work.

Comment: The XSLT does not split words - it just looks for the abbreviations using `containing`, and so expand `Valv` inside `Valve`. The `replace` template should be improved to split the words (you'll have to define what a word is incidentally), but that's way too complex for XSLT 1.0.

Comment: ...you might have explained all this a little bit better in the question, I would have saved some time