# XSLT: Replace string with Abbreviations

Tags: xslt

I would like to know how to replace the string with the abbreviations.

My XML looks like below

```
            <concept reltype="CONTAINS" name="Left Ventricular Major Axis Diastolic Dimension, 4-chamber view" type="NUM">
            <code meaning="Left Ventricular Major Axis Diastolic Dimension, 4-chamber view" value="18074-5" schema="LN" />
            <measurement value="5.7585187646">
              <code value="cm" schema="UCUM" />
            </measurement>
            <content>
              <concept reltype="HAS ACQ CONTEXT" name="Image Mode" type="CODE">
                <code meaning="Image Mode" value="G-0373" schema="SRT" />
                <code meaning="2D mode" value="G-03A2" schema="SRT" />
              </concept>
            </content>
          </concept>
```

and I am selecting some value from the xml like,

```
<xsl:value-of select="concept/measurement/code/@value"/>
```

Now what I want is, I have to replace cm with centimeter. I have so many words like this. I would like to have a xml for abbreviations and replace from them.

I saw one similar example here.

[Using a Map in XSL for expanding abbreviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521203/using-a-map-in-xsl-for-expanding-abbreviations)

But it replaces node text, but I have text as attribute. Also, it would be better for me If I can find and replace when I select text using xsl:valueof select instead of having a separate xsl:template. Please help. I am new to xslt.

Comment: What XSLT version you want to use "1.0" or "2.0"?

Comment: Where should the list of abbreviations be located? Second xml file. Same xml fil as input, or xslt file? If you are using xslt-1.0 can you use extension node-set?

Comment: Can I have the abbreviations within the xslt? I am looking for version 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created XSLT v "1.1". For abbreviations I have created XML file as you have mentioned:

**Abbreviation.xml:**

```
<Abbreviations>
  <Abbreviation>
    <Short>cm</Short>
    <Full>centimeter</Full>
  </Abbreviation>
  <Abbreviation>
    <Short>m</Short>
    <Full>meter</Full>
  </Abbreviation>
</Abbreviations>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
  <xsl:param name="AbbreviationDoc" select="document('Abbreviation.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="Convert">
      <xsl:with-param name="present" select="concept/measurement/code/@value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template name="Convert">
    <xsl:param name="present"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$AbbreviationDoc/Abbreviations/Abbreviation[Short = $present]">
        <xsl:value-of select="$AbbreviationDoc/Abbreviations/Abbreviation[Short = $present]/Full"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$present"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**INPUT:**

as you have given `<xsl:value-of select="concept/measurement/code/@value"/>`

**OUTPUT:**

```
centimeter
```

You just need to enhance this Abbreviation.xml to keep short and full value of abbreviation and call 'Convert' template with passing current value to get desired output.

Comment: Look good to me. If I'm right this should also run with xlst-1.0. (I do not see why to use parm variable should do as well)

Comment: There are two ways to run this script. First, if you are using Saxon6.5.5. keep xslt version "1.1". Second if you want to keep XSLT version "1.0" then you have to implement XSLT extension function. About param, we have two defined param 'AbbreviationDoc' (to keep Abbreviation.xml file) and 'present' to pass your XML value to our template 'Convert'.

Comment: I didn't use separate xml file. I used a variable with in my xslt.               <xsl:variable name="abbreviations">
    <abbreviation key="cm">centimeter</abbreviation>
  </xsl:variable>

Answer (score 1):

Here a little shorter version:
 - with abbreviations in xslt file
 - make use of apply-templates with mode to make usage shorter.

But with xslt 1.0 node-set extension is required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="abbreviations_txt">
        <abbreviation abbrev="cm" >centimeter</abbreviation>
        <abbreviation abbrev="m" >meter</abbreviation>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="abbreviations" select="exsl:node-set($abbreviations_txt)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="concept/measurement/code/@value" mode="abbrev_to_text"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="* | @*" mode="abbrev_to_text">
        <xsl:variable name="abbrev" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="long_text" select="$abbreviations//abbreviation[@abbrev = $abbrev]/text()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$long_text"/>
        <xsl:if test="not ($long_text)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$abbrev"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```